# Intel HD Graphics in Dell Inspiron n4030 detected as unkown

Tags: 11.04, graphics, intel, external-monitor, inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron n4030 with an Intel HD graphic card but it's detected as "unknown" graphics card and it's not working well when I use it with an external monitor Samsung Syncmaster 933sn

I have tried Ubuntu 10.10, 11.04 with the same result

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This is your [problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/614238).

Go there and mark it for resolution, so they include the fix in the official distribution